# Remove trailing forward slash and question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Quick summary, I have implemented the following .htaccess file which successfully redirects http:// and any www. searches to https://

**My issue** - After redirectrule has been applied it then leaves a trailing //? so for example: http://www.example.com becomes https://example.com//?

Another example of another page: http://www.example.com/test becomes https://example.com//test?

So to clarify further. I am happy with the http to https redirect however I only need one final trailing slash and nothing else to my URL, any help and advice would be great as I cannot for the life of me find any other example like this.

**Required** - http://www.example.com to become https://example.com/

Here is my .htaccess code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://settlerslodge.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be _all_ your rewriting? Because with what you have shown, it is not clear where that `?` should come from here in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below rewrite rule and test.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Practically there! So that leaves me with a trailing ? will this affect SEO? If not, I can live with that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a clean setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,QSD,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).